# Botpress instalada uma versão, exibindo a outra no start da aplicação

Tags: node.js, docker

Estou tentando rodar a versão 10 (`develop/x`) do `botpress`, mas sempre que dou `start` ele exibe a versão **1.1.13**

```
root@3900662b3eb1:/bot# bp start
18:49:25 - info: Starting botpress version 1.1.13
18:49:25 - info: Loaded botpress-platform-webchat, version 0.4.7
18:49:25 - info: Loaded 1 modules
18:49:25 - debug: Loading middleware: UMM.instrumentation
18:49:25 - debug: Loading middleware: hear
18:49:25 - debug: Loading middleware: conversations
18:49:25 - debug: Loading middleware: fallback
(node:127) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
    at Function.module.exports.bp (/bot/index.js:25:16)
    at botpress._callee$ (webpack-internal:///48:353:32)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botpress/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botpress/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:303:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botpress/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
    at step (webpack-internal:///48:119:191)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///48:119:361)
    at <anonymous>
```

Porém, quando mando ele mostrar sua versão, exibe corretamente a versão **10.0.2**

```
root@3900662b3eb1:/bot# bp --version
10.0.2
```

Eu estou rodando ele dentro do `Docker`, instalei utilizando o seguinte comando que está descrito na documentação.

```
npm install -g botpress@beta
```

Alguém pode me ajuda nisso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode tentar com yarn link / npm link

```
git clone https://github.com/botpress/botpress.git botpressX
cd botpressX
git checkout remotes/origin/develop/x
yarn install
yarn compile
yarn link 
cd ../otherProjectFolder
yarn link botpress 
../botpressX/bin/botpress start
```

Comment: Obrigado Matt, editei a pergunta com o resultado das tentativas usando link.

Comment: Esqueci yarn install / yarn compile!

Comment: Agora sim o link funcionou, mas ainda está utilizando a versão antiga. Mudei de máquina e re-instalei tudo. Quando eu utilizo o comando  `botpress ìnit` ele instala no `node_modules` a versão 1.1.13 do botpress.

Comment: quando vc faiz botpress init, node_modules tem o botpress 1.1, tem que fazer yarn link botpress novamente. vc pode fazer `ls -lah node_modules/ | grep botpress ` e tem que ver um symlink do botpress folder ---> botpressX cloned repo

Comment: Funcionou lindamente meu amigo Matt :D